# LibGDX v3.0.0 (connection error) during set up, third party libraries do not appear

Tags: java, libgdx

I am quite new in java and this is the first time I tried to use LibGDX. I am repeating exactly what is described in most tutorials and related youtube videos.

However, when I run "gdx-setup-ui" and press create, I am receiving the following errors:

v3.0.0 (connection error) at the left,

Master config file 0/?? (?%)

Version number file 0/?? (?%) at the bottom with red back ground.

As a result I am not able to use any third party libraries which prevents me to start programming my sweet game idea.

As far as I understand from the similar posts, this problem appears in some computers. However I have only seen two advices (close and open again, copy to D and open with cmd command window) and neither worked for me. I would greatly appreciate if you could help me get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It also doesn't work for me currently. libgdx has recently moved to a new server and it might be that this is the problem here.

The current nightly build of libgdx does not even distribute this old version of gdx-setup-ui anymore, but one that creates projects using gradle as the buildsystem. This setup allows you to add the extensions, but no third party libraries anymore.

It looks like the support for the non-gradle stuff is being dropped completely and you should switch to the new setup helper. But this means that you have to add any third party libraries yourself afterwards (which should be the standard anyway).

You can still use the old version of the setup and generate the projects without any extras though, and then add them yourself, if you don't like gradle.